# Как сделать отдельный отступ сверху для первого айтема RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть `RecyclerView` и мне нужно сделать так, чтобы у первого вложенного в него элемента был отступ (отступ от самого `RecyclerView`), но чтобы этот отступ можно было бы проскролить. Попробовал сделать с помощью `layout_marginTop` (для элемента), но это применяет отступ для всех элементов, которые создаются в `RecyclerView`. Как можно сделать такой отступ?

Comment: А что, между айтемами у вас нет отступа (должны быть слеплены в кучу) или первому требуется отступ больше чем между остальными. Разметка айтема не помешала бы

Comment: Между айтемами есть оступы, но мне нужен отступ именно между компонентами (точнее чтобы у первого компонента в списке отступ был больше чем у остальных и этот отступ можно было проскролить)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить отступ только к первому элементу можно с помощью класса `ItemDecoration`.

Создаем сам декоратор (значение `margin` указывает отступ для первого элемента в *dp*):

```
private class SpaceItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

  @Override
  public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

       // вычисление пикселей по DP. Здесь отступ будет *8dp*
       int margin = 8;
       int space = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, margin, view.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 
       if(parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0){
            outRect.top = space;
            outRect.bottom = 0;
       }
   }
}
```

При инициализации в активити `RecyclerView` подключаем наш декоратор:

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpaceItemDecoration());
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать гораздо проще. В макете, внутри `RecyclerView` устанавливаете отступы.

```
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="20dp"
```

Чтобы отступы уходили с экрана во время прокрутки списка, используйте параметр.

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
```